# How to keep warm arduino uno board with 12v dc supply

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have an arduino uno board with ESP8266 module and i have done all connection using breadboard.

Now when i run arduino uno with USB cable for long time then its not getting hot ! but when i supply power with 12v dc adapter in black barrele then its getting too much hot (i cant touch with my fingure).

Now when i remove the ESP8266 module power and test it again with 12v dc power supply then its not getting hot !

So what is the problem with ESP8266 module ? Is my wiring creates heat ?

Comment: need to show wiring diagram, and give specs on the power supplies. But the esp should not be getting that hot

Comment: What is the "it" that is getting hot?

Comment: @NickGammon Arduino bottom part of that black barrele.

Comment: @ChadG yes its readlly getting hot. ! i have also attchaed 5 v realy

Comment: Also asked at: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=538176 If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.

Comment: Is the ESP8266 working as expected?

Comment: you're not supposed to power the esp01 from an UNO. if you do, at least drop vin down to 7v.

Answer (score 4):

See [Can I use arduino's 3.3 V output directly to esp8266?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23815/can-i-use-arduinos-3-3-v-output-directly-to-esp8266/23819)

From that page:

> The specs for the Uno say that it does not provide as much current on the 3.3V line as the specs for the ESP8266 requires. You will need to provide another regulator that can supply enough current.

Also, putting 12V into the barrel jack is making work for the on-board voltage regulator (located near the barrel jack) because it has to convert 12V to 5V (making heat in the process). You would be better off putting a lower voltage into the barrel jack, ideally around 7V (but not lower).

Alternatively, just power through the USB port as you have been, and plug the USB cable into a USB charger.

---

To summarize, both the 5V and 3.3V voltage regulators are probably working very hard, thus getting hot.